# Test if numpy array contains only zeros

Tags: python, numpy

We initialize a numpy array with zeros as bellow:

```
np.zeros((N,N+1))
```

But how do we check whether all elements in a given n*n numpy array matrix is zero.
The method just need to return a True if all the values are indeed zero.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Check out [numpy.count_nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html#numpy.count_nonzero).

```
>>> np.count_nonzero(np.eye(4))
4
>>> np.count_nonzero([[0,1,7,0,0],[3,0,0,2,19]])
5
```

Comment: You'd want `not np.count_nonzero(np.eye(4))` to return `True` only if all the values are 0.

Comment: `array.nonzero()[0].size == 0` tends to be faster in practice

Answer (score 235):

The other answers posted here will work, but the clearest and most efficient function to use is [`numpy.any()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.any.html):

```
>>> all_zeros = not np.any(a)
```

or

```
>>> all_zeros = not a.any()
```

- This is preferred over `numpy.all(a==0)` because it uses less RAM. (It does not require the temporary array created by the `a==0` term.)
- <strike>Also, it is faster than `numpy.count_nonzero(a)` because it can return immediately when the first nonzero element has been found.</strike>

  - **Edit:** As @Rachel pointed out in the comments, `np.any()` no longer uses "short-circuit" logic, so you won't see a speed benefit for small arrays.

Comment: As of a minute ago, numpy's `any` and `all` do **not** short-circuit. I believe they are sugar for `logical_or.reduce` and `logical_and.reduce`. Compare to each other and my short-circuiting `is_in`:

`all_false = np.zeros(10**8)`
`all_true = np.ones(10**8)`

`%timeit np.any(all_false) 91.5 ms ± 1.82 ms per loop`

`%timeit np.any(all_true) 93.7 ms ± 6.16 ms per loop`

`%timeit is_in(1, all_true) 293 ns ± 1.65 ns per loop`

Comment: That's a great point, thanks.  It looks like short-circuiting *used* to be the behavior, but that was lost at some point. There is some interesting discussion in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771554/why-isnt-numpy-any-lazy-short-circuiting).

Answer (score 75):

I'd use np.all here, if you have an array a:

```
>>> np.all(a==0)
```

Comment: I like that this answer checks for non zero values as well. For example, one can check whether all elements in an array are the same by doing `np.all(a==a[0])`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This solution is also a little more efficient than `np.count_nonzero`.

%timeit num_of_non_zeros = np.count_nonzero(zeros_vector)
18.2 µs ± 386 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit num_of_non_zeros = np.all((zeros_vector == 0))
7.31 µs ± 41.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Answer (score 14):

As another answer says, you can take advantage of truthy/falsy evaluations if you know that `0` is the only falsy element possibly in your array. All elements in an array are falsy iff there are not any truthy elements in it.*

```
>>> a = np.zeros(10)
>>> not np.any(a)
True
```

However, the answer claimed that `any` was faster than other options due partly to short-circuiting. As of 2018, Numpy's `all` and `any` **do not short-circuit**.

If you do this kind of thing often, it's very easy to make your own short-circuiting versions using `numba`:

```
import numba as nb

# short-circuiting replacement for np.any()
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def sc_any(array):
    for x in array.flat:
        if x:
            return True
    return False

# short-circuiting replacement for np.all()
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def sc_all(array):
    for x in array.flat:
        if not x:
            return False
    return True
```

These tend to be faster than Numpy's versions even when not short-circuiting. `count_nonzero` is the slowest.

Some input to check performance:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10**8
middle = n//2
all_0 = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
all_1 = np.ones(n, dtype=int)
mid_0 = np.ones(n, dtype=int)
mid_1 = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
np.put(mid_0, middle, 0)
np.put(mid_1, middle, 1)
# mid_0 = [1 1 1 ... 1 0 1 ... 1 1 1]
# mid_1 = [0 0 0 ... 0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
```

Check:

```
## count_nonzero
%timeit np.count_nonzero(all_0) 
# 220 ms ± 8.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit np.count_nonzero(all_1)
# 150 ms ± 4.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

### all
# np.all
%timeit np.all(all_1)
%timeit np.all(mid_0)
%timeit np.all(all_0)
# 56.8 ms ± 3.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# 57.4 ms ± 1.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# 55.9 ms ± 2.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# sc_all
%timeit sc_all(all_1)
%timeit sc_all(mid_0)
%timeit sc_all(all_0)
# 44.4 ms ± 2.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# 22.7 ms ± 599 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# 288 ns ± 6.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

### any
# np.any
%timeit np.any(all_0)
%timeit np.any(mid_1)
%timeit np.any(all_1)
# 60.7 ms ± 1.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# 60 ms ± 287 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# 57.7 ms ± 1.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# sc_any
%timeit sc_any(all_0)
%timeit sc_any(mid_1)
%timeit sc_any(all_1)
# 41.7 ms ± 1.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# 22.4 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# 287 ns ± 12.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

* Helpful `all` and `any` equivalences:

```
np.all(a) == np.logical_not(np.any(np.logical_not(a)))
np.any(a) == np.logical_not(np.all(np.logical_not(a)))
not np.all(a) == np.any(np.logical_not(a))
not np.any(a) == np.all(np.logical_not(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
def check(arr):
    if np.all(arr == 0):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: you could just do return np.all(arr == 0)

Answer (score 2):

If all elements in ur array are larger or equal than 0. I think use sum is the fastest way.

```
test = np.ones((128, 128, 128))
%%timeit
not np.any(test)
>>> 1.46 ms ± 9.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%%timeit
np.sum(test) == 0
>>> 646 µs ± 3.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to classify 1e-15's as zero:

```
def all_zero( numpy_array ):
    return np.allclose( numpy_array, np.zeros_like(numpy_array) )
```

Answer (score -10):

If you're testing for all zeros to avoid a warning on another numpy function then wrapping the line in a try, except block will save having to do the test for zeros before the operation you're interested in i.e.

```
try: # removes output noise for empty slice 
    mean = np.mean(array)
except:
    mean = 0
```