# How to detect empty wave file in Python?

Tags: python, wave

I am trying to sort through a bunch of audio samples where some of them are fully blank. Can someone help me figure out the best way to detect if a file is blank (silent) for its duration? I've found a bunch of ways of reading wav files, but thus far nothing on how to determine if a file is blank.

The code I have thus far:

```
import soundfile as sf

path = '/Users/InNov8/Desktop/Elektron_Octotrack_Chain_Maker_v2/Bar 25 -- High 303/'

file1 = 'Bar 25 --- [tr] ---  4-Kick 2.aif' # blank
file2 = 'Bar 25 --- [tr] ---  10 Shaker.aif' # not blank
file3 = 'Bar 25 --- [tr] ---  14 HARD SNARE.aif' # blank

f1 = path + file1
x, fs = sf.read(f1)
print x
print fs
f2 = path + file2
x, fs = sf.read(f2)
print x
print fs
```

Comment: Its variance or standard deviation is a very small number.??

Answer (score 2):

Check that the data in the file contains only zeroes. The `soundfile` module is based on NumPy, so you can do that using some functions which are a fair bit faster than just using `any()`.  See: [Test if numpy array contains only zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395725/test-if-numpy-array-contains-only-zeros)

Note that just because a file *sounds* blank doesn't mean that it's actually all zeroes. It could just be very quiet, or contain a small amount of noise.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting "false" result for the any() test for all files, where I'm testing an "empty" file and one that clearly has sound. As such, is there a way to test if the volume of the file is below a certain threshold, b/c your point about the very quiet file causing a glitch is what seems to be happening.

Comment: It's not really a glitch, but a quiet file is not the same as a silent file. You can either test the RMS value of the file or the peak values (say, the size of `np.max(data) - np.min(data)`).

Comment: Neither of these values are really "volume", since volume is a psychoacoustic phenomenon. But they will give you different ways of measuring the signal magnitude.

Comment: How about variance or standard deviation?

Comment: @wwii: a.k.a. RMS

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have bunch of audio files and some of them are below a certain threshold that are causing issue.
If you are open to using external libraries, you can use [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) to detect if given `audio_segment` is above/below given threshold.

First of all , you can install `pydub` on windows using

```
   pip install pydub
```

Next you can load audio file (example is for `wav`, but you can find methods to load other types of files in the [link](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)).

Per website:

> **AudioSegment(…).dBFS**
>   Returns the loudness of the AudioSegment in dBFS (db relative to the maximum possible loudness). A Square wave at maximum amplitude will be roughly 0 dBFS (maximum loudness), whereas a Sine Wave at maximum amplitude will be roughly -3 dBFS

Load file and find out its loudness

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("sound1.wav")

loudness = sound.dBFS
```

You can load multiple files and compare loudness as above.

Alternately, if you are looking for loudness for certain portion of a file, then you will need to split audio segment in chunks and then check loudness for each chunk. Again, you can find details on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dietrich Epp for putting me on the right track.

Here's the code that works to move the nearly empty files to another directory

```
import soundfile as np
import os
import sys
import shutil


path = '/Users/InNov8/Desktop/Elektron_Octotrack_Chain_Maker_v2/'

source = 'Bar 25 -- High 303/'

dst = 'Bar 25 -- High 303 -- blank/'


source_path = path + source
dst_path = path + dst

files = []

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source_path):
    for filename in filenames:
        if 'aif' in filename or 'wav' in filename:
            if 'asd' not in filename:
                print os.path.join(dirname, filename)
                files.append(filename)


for f in files:
    x, fs = np.read(source_path + f)
    vol_rms =  x.max() - x.min()

    print f
    print vol_rms

    if vol_rms <= 6.103515625e-05:
        print '\n\nTRUE'
        print 'MOVE: ', source_path + f
        print 'DST: ', dst_path + f
        shutil.move(source_path + f, dst_path + f)

    print '\n\n\n'
```